# Big wasted space at Text soft line break

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am building a chat screen using Jetpack Compose, Each message draw a column that takes the full width of the screen, and inside the column, I draw a time Text at the center of the screen width, and below the time I draw a message Text that takes between 0 and 0.75 of the screen width. If the message width is bigger than 0.75 of the screen width it takes multiple lines, but I notice that the space at soft line break is very big and ugly, how can I reduce it? I want to achieve the same result in the left image below.

```
@Composable
fun MessageRow() {
    Column {
        // here goes time then a surface contains message
        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
            modifier = Modifier
                .widthIn(0.dp, 265.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "I was distraught to attend the meeting.",
                color = Color.Black
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947555/3585796)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov did not work.

Comment: could you add details what have you done and why it didn't worked out for you? [Here is](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/1438ad56963611cdc3fa05f915457f07) your sample with my solution, which produces [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vN9K.png) which seems exactly what you've being looking for.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov sorry, it did not work in Compose preview, but now I tried it in the emulator and it worked, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It cannot work in Preview because it requires a single recomposition - after `onTextLayout` result is received. If [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947555/3585796) helped you, please give it an upvote.