# Jetpack Compose: multiline Text in Row with weight and wrapping text content

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Row` layout with two Composables inside:

- `Text` that should wrap itself width and take as much space as possible when content is lengthy
- `Image` that has to be present every time on the right side of `Text`

To achieve both, I'm currently using `weight(weight = 1f, fill = false)` for `Text` Composable. And it works fine for single line content. However, it creates an issue with line breaking and wrapping multiline text. For clearer view, I've added `background(Color.Yellow)` and some long words. See reference code:

```
Row {
    Text(
        text = "This is the message with quite super-unprecedented words",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .weight(
                weight = 1f,
                fill = false
            )
    )

    Image(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.image),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

And the result looks like this:
[image: Screen]

Is it possible to remove the padding at the end of `Text` so `Image` could fit closely to `Text` in multiline case as well? Or any other ideas how to achieve this? I've already taken a look on `softWrap` parameter for `Text` and `requireSize` for `Image` but with no big luck.

Comment: It's a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206039942), check out some workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947555/3585796).

Answer (score 0):

Now you can achieve this by applying line break property and setting strictness to loose in text style.

```
 style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall.copy(
                fontSize = 8.sp,
                lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph.copy(strictness = LineBreak.Strictness.Loose)
            )
```