# Jetpack Compose Text having extra padding when wrapping to next line

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a a text element with an icon to its right, both wrapped in a Row. The text has a `1.0f` weight with `fill = false`. When a word wraps to the next line, the text has some padding at the end of it causing the icon to be too far apart from it. This is what it looks like:

[App Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQNQG.png)

Here is the code:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp)
) {
    Text(
        "John Doe John Doe John Doe",
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f, fill = false).background(Color.Green)
    )
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Done,
        contentDescription = "",
    )
}
```

How do I make it so the text's width wraps itself without adding that extra spacing?

Comment: How about giving both `Text` and `Icon` some weight e.g. set the Text weight at `.9f` and Icon's weight at `.1f`. This will ensure they are equally separated even with wrapping

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736096/jetpack-compose-multiline-text-in-row-with-weight-and-wrapping-text-content
This is a known bug. Workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947555/495739

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior. It happens because you set weight for your Text and a width modifier for your Row.

It's kind of unavoidable when setting a specific width or height. It may happen even if you set weight for both Composables inside the Row (0.1f and 0.9f). Because the word can't fit in the remaining space but the Composable must fill the Row
[image]

You set the row width to 150.dp and when your Text has a weight modifier, it fills the row even if a word in your Text composable doesn't fit in the line.